# How to compare column value in csv

Tags: python, csv, python-2.x

I tend to compare two column value like:

```
 name        columnA     columnB
hahaha        [123]        123
```

one with square brackets,one without square brackets. Id like to verify the content in bracket（123） is same as the value under columnB（123）

First  read these value:

```
with open('2.csv','rb') as csvfile:
reader3 = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for row in reader3:
    if row['name']== 'hahaha':
        b=row['columnA']
        c=row['columnB']
```

and I try to extract content from bracket by:

```
e = re.findall(r'\[([^]]*)\]',b)
```

I print c and e. output is `['123'] [123]`
now I dont know how to make ['123'] = [123]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why not: `b = row['columnA'].strip('[]')`? Then you could just check for `b == c`.

Comment: Your regex is definitely incorrect. You should use a capture group like this - `r'\[(.*?)\]'`, not how you're doing right now.

Comment: Also, the result of `re.findall` is being assigned to `c`, overwriting the old `c` value. Did you mean to do that?

Comment: I changed that is my mistake @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to remove braces from a string, you could do so with `str.strip` -

```
>>> '[1234]'.strip('[]')
'1234'
```

As for your current method, your regular expression is the culprit here. I'm not sure what you think it does, but it definitely isn't right. One possible regex solution would be -

```
>>> re.match(r'\[(.*?)\]', '[1234]').group(1)
'1234'
```

```
\[      # opening brace 
(.*?)   # match-all capture group
\]      # closing brace
```

Comment: very useful answer！now everything is ok！ thank you mate！